# how to download audio from website via google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, view, download, mp3, google-translate

I used to copy (download) audio from Google translate using 'view code' command, and passing to network tab. and when i played the text,mp3 file appeared in 'media' section.
Now i tried to do this using new MS Edge, it didn't work out,
please, answer 2 questions:
1.how did it happen?
2.how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but overcame it by using the same technique in vocaflash instead of google translate. Adding new words or phrases to the flash card sheet will generate the mp3 files you are looking for.

Comment: i also solved the problem with temporary method, you can see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUbm1rHsujg

Comment: your method is not acceptable for me because, i ve already had vocabulary saved, which i need to export.